# Gulpjs webserver access from local network

Tags: javascript, html

I've been using gulpjs task runner for the front-end and I always need to watch how my html files look after them change. So, I've configured the webserver plugin of gulp (live-reload is included), but I want to check my pages from other devices (phones, tablets, e.g.). My answer is:

How can I use gulp webserver from other devices of my local network? Thank you!

## gulpjs

Answer (score 12):

Unless I'm missing something here, as long as there's not a firewall running on your machine, you should be able to use the local network IP address of your local machine followed by the port number used by the gulp webserver. For example, if your machine IP is 192.168.0.4 and the gulp server is running on port 4000, you should be able to put http://192.168.0.4:4000/ into the browser of another device on your network and access the page.

Edit: after looking at the documentation for gulp-webserver, I found this in their FAQ (located on the GitHub readme.md https://github.com/schickling/gulp-webserver):

#### Why can't I reach the server from the network?

*Solution:* Set 0.0.0.0 as host option.

https://github.com/schickling/gulp-webserver

Comment: I have just disabled the firewall, but it's not working yet...I'm on Ubuntu 14.10. I've also tried to use apache server for local network access and don't got it. Hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: My gulp webserver was already set as 0.0.0.0 host along these days, you're right. However, it didn't work, but finally I got it!. I had forgotten a significant detail: Yes, I'm on Ubuntu, but as a virtual machine on VMware Player. The problem was that the configuration of the network adapter options was wrong. The solution is the following:

Open the Virtual Machine Settings window, go to Network Adapter option and set the Network Connection as **Bridged**. 

Just so, the local network access to the gulp webserver (or apache server) will be working nicely!

Thank you for your support.

Comment: You can read more about Bridge mode on [https://dacosta51.wordpress.com/2008/08/07/vmware-configuracin-de-red-en-modo-bridge/](https://dacosta51.wordpress.com/2008/08/07/vmware-configuracin-de-red-en-modo-bridge/)

Comment: thanks!! This is what i need to connect from my VM to host gulp server